Real part of holomorphic function on connected open set is uniquely determined by its imaginary part?
In Complex Analysis by Freitag and Busam, 2nd edition, there is this following statement,
“The real part of a function which is analytic in a connected open set $D\subset \mathbb C$ is uniquely determined by its imaginary part, up to an additive constant”,
on page 53. By analytic in $D$, they mean complex differentiable at every point in $D$ and they define a subset of $\mathbb C$ to be connected if every locally constant function on this subset is constant.
I am not sure how to precisely interpret this statement, ie put it into precise mathematical terms. Here is my attempt (perhaps wrong),
Let $D\subset \mathbb C$ be open and connected. Let $f:D\to \mathbb C$ be analytic in $D$ with imaginary part $v(x,y)$. Then, the real part is $u(x,y)=v(x,y)+c$ for some $c\in \mathbb C$ constant.
Or do they mean $u(x,y)=g(v(x,y))+c$ for some composable function $g$?

None of the above. By uniquely determined they mean that if two holomorphic functions $f_1, f_2:D\to\mathbb{C}$ have the same imaginary part, then their real parts are equal up to a constant. In other words, if $f_1=u_1+iv_1, f_2=u_2+iv_2$, and $v_1=v_2$ on $D$, then there is a constant $c$ such that $u_1=u_2+c$.
This easily follows from the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Thank you, makes sense :)
